# 3D Pandas DataFrame from csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am fairly new to pandas, and need to import a 3D array of tuples from a data file. In the file, the data is formatted as so:

```
[[(1.1, 1.2), (1.3, 1.4)], [(1.5, 1.6), (1.7, 1.8)], [(1.9, 1.10), (1.11, 1.12)], [(1.13, 1.14), (1.15, 1.16)]]
[[(2.1, 2.2), (2.3, 2.4)], [(2.5, 2.6), (2.7, 2.8)], [(2.9, 2.10), (2.11, 2.12)], [(2.13, 2.14), (2.15, 2.16)]]
[[(3.1, 3.2), (3.3, 3.4)], [(3.5, 3.6), (3.7, 3.8)], [(3.9, 3.10), (3.11, 3.12)], [(3.13, 3.14), (3.15, 3.16)]]
```

I would like to be able to import this into a data frame such that (for this example) the dimensionality would be 3x4x2 (with another x2, if you want to count the dimensions of the tuples, though those don't necessarily need their own dimension, so long as I can access them as tuples).

In actuality, my data set is much larger than this (with dimensions of roughly 13000x2000x2), so I would like to keep any manual editing that might be needed to a minimum, though I should be able to change how the data is formatted in the file with some simple scripts, if a different format would help.

Comment: Have you considered using Panels? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html

Comment: As @Diego Agher said, there is no such thing as a 3d dataframe, what does exist is  `panel`, which is something similar. The problem in my opinion is that you are not specifying how you want to read your data and what format the data file you read them from is. If you add that maybe we can be more helpful

Comment: The format of the file is what's shown above (in an otherwise plaintext file). Currently I'm just using `read_csv` to read the data in, though that's clearly not working, and I'm not sure how I would specify the format of the file further than just the deliminator. I'll try looking into `panel`s though, to see if they could work, and what functions can read from my data file into a panel.

Comment: I should also add that not using pandas is also an option, but so far pandas is the only library that has been able to import anything at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even 'eval' is a dangerous tool it gives here a one-liner to collect the data :

```
with open('data.csv') as f: a=np.array([eval(x) for x in f.readlines()])
```

check :

```
In [59]: a.shape
Out[59]: (3, 4, 2, 2)
```

Comment: This worked! Takes a little while, but that's ok. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a multidimensional `dataframe` with `pandas`.
You could think of several `dataframes` and have them relate to each other with an extra column as an `id`.

Or you could also flatten your 3D array to `dataframe` with several columns:

- your rows would be the observation, in this case 3
- your columns would be the flatten output 4 x 2 = 8

You could use `numpy` to reshape:

```
new_array = numpy.reshape(array, (3,8))
```